# Visual Studio 2013 CLR SP debugging on local MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, clr, sql-server-2014

I'm currently pulling my hair out here. I have an SQL Server Database project in Visual Studio 2013, which contains a CLR SP. I have a test script created in order to call the SP and enable me to debug it. I can build, make changes and publish\deploy to my SQL Server 2014 no problem. However, when I set a break point on my test script I can step into the test, but when it then calls the CLR SP it doesn't hit any of the breakpoints I've set in it. Instead I get Dynamic Transact-SQL windows popping up with any SQL executed within my CLR SP, which is not help at all as the logic I want to debug is the c# code.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Stu.

Comment: I hadn't enabled CLR SP debugging, which overcame the above issue, then I hadn't run VS 2013 as administrator; all steps documented in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180009/unable-to-debug-net-code-could-not-attach-to-process-sql-clr-remote-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my comment above for the answer to this problem.